# Showing bootstraps modal after redicted to page

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been making a website where settings.php and saveSettings.php page where it insert `$_POST` functions to database.

Here is part of settings.php

```
echo '
  <form action="saveSettings.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control no-resize" rows="4" id="profilecomment" name="profilecomment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" style="margin-top:10px" value="Submit" />
  </form>
';
```

and here part of saveSettings.php

```
$userComment = $_POST["profilecomment"];

$updateComment = "UPDATE users SET comment = '$userComment' WHERE steamid = '$steamID' ";

header('Location: settings.php');
```

This is what I have tried:

I added my modal load script to settings.php page

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#settingsSave').modal('show');
  });
</script>
```

And modal script:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="settingsSave" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>You have successfully saved your settings!</p>                     
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if it does not popup because of that:

```
header('Location: settings.php');
```

I hope I can get some help.

Comment: The `modal` HTML is also in `settings.php` right? Can you do a `console.log` inside `$(window).load(function(){});` or in general check your Javascript console for any errors?

Comment: Hello yea it is, @Javan R answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please be aware of **mysql Injection**, I see you dont escape your POST parameters.

Do it like this:

```
$userComment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["profilecomment"]);
```

or **use mysqli instead of mysql**

**To your question:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
       $('#settingsSave').modal('show');
 });
```

is wrong, you must use something like:

`$( document ).ready(function() {
    <?
    if(isset($_GET['save'])){
           echo "$('#settingsSave').modal('show');";
    }
    ?>
    });`

ans pass a parameter to your new location

```
header('Location: settings.php?save');
```

Comment: Hello, i have prevented from mysql injection, i just did not pasted them to my thread since i was not asking about that. I tested your code on the settings.php, it showed the script everytime i loaded page, on saveSettings.php it did not worked.

Comment: I see, sorry. Yes there are different ways to solve this problem. You can pass a parameter in your location like: `header('Location: settings.php?saved');` and then when this parameter is set you can show the modal

Comment: How should add the saved parameter in JavaScript?  I havent learned JS so much yet.

Comment: It did not worked first, but i added `<?php` instead of  `<?` and it worked.